# Ensuring Multiple Implementations are Valid

Tags: c#, programming-practices

I'll preface this with a few classes that shows what I'm trying to do

```
interface IDataField { /* ... */ }

class DataFieldImplementationA : IDataField { /* ... */ }

class DataFieldImplementationB : IDataField { /* ... */ }

interface IData
{
    IDataField Field { get; }
}

class DataImplementationA : IData
{
    public DataFieldImplementationA Field { get; set; }

    IDataField IData.Field => this.Field; // this gets messy quickly
}

class DataImplementationB : IData
{
    public DataFieldImplementationB Field { get; set; }

    IDataField IData.Field => this.Field; // this gets messy quickly
}

class Program
{
    static T Load<T>(/* ... */) where T : IData { /* ... */ }
    static void Save(IData data) { /* ... */ }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // load as a specific implementation, this is working fine
        var a = Load<DataImplementationA>( /* ... */ );
        var b = Load<DataImplementationB>( /* ... */ );
        // save as any implementation, the saving system just cares about the data
        Save(a);
        Save(b);
    }
}
```

What I have is two different internal representations of the same data. One is a flat data and one supports and tracks inheritance in the data. I need both to do different kinds of processing.

I am specifically interested in finding out if there is a better approach to enforce the different properties without having to have a matching explicit interface property on my two data implementations, the lines where I write "this gets messy quickly".

My goal with the interface is if I update the interfaces, this will force me to update both my implementations, so they both stay working and matching.

In short, I need two classes to always have the same same properties, but the implementation of those properties might be different from the two classes. Doing this with interfaces seems obvious, but as properties can be different implementations, I run into a need for explicit interface implementations which gets messy for large data classes.

**Question**: How do I ensure two classes have the same properties with the least bit of trouble?

*Disclaimer: I ask this, knowing full well I might be going about this the wrong way. If there is a different way to do what I'm doing, those answers are welcome as well.*

Comment: I don't really understand your reasoning for needing the explicit interface implementation

Comment: To satisfy the interface. Even though `DataFieldImplementationA` inherits from `IDataField` it still doesn't satisfy the interface `IData`. This comes from the fact that if I add a setter, it wouldn't make sense since I couldn't assign any `IDataField` to it. The limitation makes perfect sense, I'm just trying to find a sensible way to work around it.

Comment: How are you able to load? I'm guessing `Load` has to write to the public `Field` property, yet it has to do so with an object of the correct type, perhaps by some conversion from whatever type the data source gives you. If such type and conversion exists, you can declare `Field` in `IData` as the type the data source gives you (which can be converted), that way you can have an implicit implementation with the conversion in the property assessor. If that data type and conversion from it to the different implementations don't exist, make them exist.

Comment: Would avoiding public setters be possible?

Answer (score 1):

I may have missed something (or am making too much of extra assumptions), but why not:

```
public interface IDataField { /* ... */ }

public class DataFieldImplementationA : IDataField { /* ... */ }

public class DataFieldImplementationB : IDataField { /* ... */ }

public interface IData
{
    void LoadFrom<TArgs>(TArgs args);

    IDataField Field { get; }
}

public abstract class DataImplementationBase<TDataField> : IData
    where TDataField : class, IDataField, new()
{
    protected TDataField _field;

    public abstract void LoadFrom<TArgs>(TArgs args);

    public IDataField Field => _field ?? (_field = new TDataField());
}

public class DataImplementationA : DataImplementationBase<DataFieldImplementationA>
{
    public override void LoadFrom<TArgs>(TArgs args)
    {
        /* load _field from args
           (will need cast, eg: ... (int)args ...) */
    }
}

public class DataImplementationB : DataImplementationBase<DataFieldImplementationB>
{
    public override void LoadFrom<TArgs>(TArgs args)
    {
        /* load _field from args
           (will need cast, eg: ... (string)args ...) */
    }
}

class Program
{
    static TData Load<TData, TArgs>(TData prototype, TArgs args)
        where TData : class, IData, new()
    {
        var data = new TData();
        data.LoadFrom(args);
        return data;
    }

    static void Save(IData data) { /* ... */ }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // load as a specific implementation, this is working fine
        var a = Load(default(DataImplementationA), 123);
        var b = Load(default(DataImplementationB), "foo");
        // save as any implementation, the saving system just cares about the data
        Save(a);
        Save(b);
    }
}
```

?

Rationale:

I understood you want different implementations of IData be constrained by the concrete type of different implementations of IDataField;

hence, the use of the generic parameter constraint (TDataField) on the base generic class DataImplementationBase;

further, descendants of the latter, precisely for implementation purpose, will need to have access to the strongly typed, specialized IDataField implementation, hence the protected TDataField member (_field) used to implement the getter of the IData's Field property.

Finally, loading an instance of IData will likely require a typed caller context which will vary with the concrete implementation type chosen for IData, hence the introduction of a generic LoadFrom(TArgs args) method on the IData interface.

The "TData prototype" parameter of the static Load helper method is just for convenient type inference along with the args at the call sites.

Comment: While I agree, that the use of generics may be viable here, you should maybe elaborate your answer a bit more, rather than just tossing out some code.

Comment: @PaulK ... done.